# How to load records in real time using PHP & jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a system using php from which we can add Status messages or you can say a kind of Microblog. So it has a database table like below :

```
posts_mst
------------------
post_id_pk
post_title
post_content
date_added
```

Now I have displayed all these posts on a page using select Query and it is displaying all the posts on a single page nicely. But now I have extended the page functionality and added a form to add these posts from same page. So that form stands on the very top of the page, and below it all the posts are getting listed.

I am storing all the posts using jquery .ajax() method so page do not load while saving any post. So now what I want to do is, when I add any posts, it should keep adding the same posts on the list in a real time, like you see in a Facebook - when someone posts on their wall, we see it loaded on the spot on our News feed. Here I want to do the same, as this page will be used by so may people and posts are displayed to everyone.

There is one way I can do this is - I can append a Div tag to the list of posts everytime a New post is added. This Div content I can get using Ajax response. But that will work for only My added post. If someone else adds the Post, I will not be knowing that.

So can anyone suggest me how I can implement this ? If there is any specific plugin used for that then let me know. :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a javascript `setTimeout` every X minutes / seconds and use ajax in the timeout function to check for new posts. You can track of what's new by storing a timestamp of the latest update in a session for example.

Note that this is periodic polling, it is not really realtime.

There are newer ways to maintain a permanent connection to the server, but that's a whole other story.